# Creating another menu in the same window

Tags: python, tkinter

So, here's the deal, i have designed a menu (main) in python using the tkinter module, and what I want is that when I click on a button on the main menu, it opens up another menu (slave), but inside the same window the main menu was. (there is an "Return to main menu" button in the slave menu, so I would like to get back to the main menu if I click this button)

Now, when I click a button, it opens up a new window containing the selected menu...

this is my code so far

```
from Tkinter import *

def cars ():

    cars = Tk ()
    Label (cars, text = "Cars Menu").grid (row = 0, columnspan = 2, pady = 20)
    Button (cars, text = "Car list", width = 50).grid (row = 1)
    Button (cars, text = "New car", width = 50).grid (row = 2)
    Button (cars, text = "Erase car", width = 50).grid (row = 3)
    Button (cars, text = "Return to main menu", width = 50).grid (row = 4, pady = 20)

root = Tk ()

Label (root, text = "Main Menu").grid (row = 0, columnspan = 2, pady = 20)
Button (root, text = "Cars", width = 30, command = cars).grid (row = 1, column = 0)
Button (root, text = "Bikes", width = 30).grid (row = 1, column = 1)

root.mainloop ()
```

Comment: Hi, can you show some code and describe what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I inderstand u correctly : you have main menu with options,and when you click on some option,you want to remove main menu and show another one on its place.I had a similar problem and I think this could help you:

I have the following function:

```
def _switch_major_panel(self, panel_to_switch_with):
    self.major_panel.grid_remove()
    self.major_panel = panel_to_switch_with
    self.major_panel.grid(sticky='nwes')
    self.update()
```

: here self is `Frame` object,so is `major_panel`.`major_panel` is an attribute to my `class Application`.Your's may be something like `current_menu` or something like that.

What I do is this: every time I want to change what my content of `major_panel` is I create a new `Frame` with the new content and simply use this function to replace the old one.Try that.

I'm far from an expert but that worked for me.

Good luck